# use exchange server with Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, exchange

I need a quick tutorial on using Thunderbird in place of outlook for my Exchange account. I need to be able to accept meeting invites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well you would have to have [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) and [Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/) and bring them together with [Lightning](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) (Beta).

Tutorial to setup Thunderbird alone: http://fourforces.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/setup-mozilla-thunderbird-to-work-with-microsoft-exchange-server/

Comment: The blog link is protected, you have to be a registered user to access it.